# jagged edges in mosaic DEM

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcpy, mosaic

I encounter edge issues when trying to mosaic USGS NED DEMs in ArcGIS 10.0.0. After projection and aggregation, I attempt `arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management()`. I've reproduced the same results using .tif, .img, and GRID formats. I've also reproduced the result using file geodatabases and file folders to store inputs and outputs. I've also tried using `arcpy.Mosaic_management()` with no luck. Note the unwelcome black border on the bottom which is problematic for analytical applications.

What can be done about the edge issues here?

This question was split from [parallelization of raster mosaic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46780).

[image] + [image] = [image]

Comment: If you have a polygon representing the outline of the mosaic or each of the individual input rasters maybe you could use this to set an analysis mask. I know this does not solve the problem of the black edges but it might allow you to carry out your analysis. You could also convert all the images to points and create a terrain and use this in your analysis.